# mapping wilcoxon-rank-sum- test on groups

Tags: r, dictionary, purrr

So I am trying to perform a wilcoxon-rank-sum-test on a grouped dataframe. The variables "Feuchte"(=numeric) and "Transtyp" (=factor) shall be tested for each group (soll) I would like to have a datframe that includes the p-value for each group as an output.

My df looks like this:

```
BF_all_soll <- structure(list(Datum = structure(c(18758, 18758, 18758, 18758, 
18758, 18758, 18758, 18758, 18758, 18758, 18758, 18758, 18758, 
18758, 18758, 18758), class = "Date"), Soll = c("1189", "1189", 
"119", "119", "1192", "1192", "1202", "1202", "149", "149", "172", 
"172", "2484", "2484", "552", "552"), Transtyp = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("2", 
"5"), class = "factor"), Feuchte = c(11.9171875, 14.078125, 10.7153846153846, 
10.6387096774194, 13.675, 13.7896551724138, 18.5, 17.071875, 
12.390625, 9.690625, 12.3935483870968, 11.6, 10.578125, 10.21875, 
13.021875, 13.225), kumsum = c(25.04, 25.04, 20.77, 20.77, 25.04, 
25.04, 25.04, 25.04, 20.77, 20.77, 20.77, 20.77, 25.04, 25.04, 
25.04, 25.04)), row.names = c(NA, -16L), groups = structure(list(
    Soll = c("1189", "1189", "119", "119", "1192", "1192", "1202", 
    "1202", "149", "149", "172", "172", "2484", "2484", "552", 
    "552"), Transtyp = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("2", "5"), class = "factor"), 
    .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
        10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The code I have written so far is this:

```
BF_all_soll %>% split( BF_all_soll$Soll) %>%
                map( ~wilcox.test(Feuchte ~ Transtyp, data = BF_all_soll))%>%
                map_dfr(~ broom::tidy(.)) ->bla
```

However, the output cant be right. The p-values are all the same.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you are using the same data (`BF_all_soll`) in `wilcox.test`. To use data specific to each group use `.x` in `map`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

BF_all_soll %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  split(.$Soll) %>%
  map_df( ~broom::tidy(wilcox.test(Feuchte ~ Transtyp, data = .x))) -> bla
```

This again gives the same p-value on the data shared but should give you correct p-values on bigger data.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works! What does .x mean exactly? Can you elaborate, because I am not really sure if I understand. Also, why do you ungroup first and then split? Cheers!

Comment: We are splitting the dataset by `Soll`, `.x` is the way to refer subset of the dataframe for each split. You are referring it as `BF_all_soll` in your code which is the complete dataframe and not the subset. `ungroup` is not necessary here. It would give the same output without it but the `dput` that you shared is grouped and it is a good practice to ungroup data when it is not needed.

Comment: How can I keep the column "Soll" in the output, so I know which p.value belongs to which group or "Soll" Thanks!

Comment: In `map_df` step add an id column i.e change the last line to `map_df( ~broom::tidy(wilcox.test(Feuchte ~ Transtyp, data = .x)), .id = 'Soll')`.